# Passing and Populate field values in Salesforce Cases after redirecting from an ASP.Net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, salesforce

We have an Asp .net application , in which we have a button ; which when clicked takes you the salesforce create case page. Is it possible that when we take them to the create case page, I can pass some values and populate some fields on that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really a Salesforce-specific question ;)
Using URL parameters to prepopulate forms is quite common, you need to know `name` of the field you want to fill in and you're good to go.

For example: `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=salesforce`

http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-url-hacking-to-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-page-layout.html is a classic blog post you can read
There are some well known field names (for standard field), short list can be found for example on http://phollaio.tumblr.com/post/22058016777/how-to-obtain-a-field-id but I'd like to stress out the fact that all you need is to inspect the source of the page and experiment.

Sample prepopulated Case form (depends which fields you show on the layout and what picklist values you have!): `https://na5.salesforce.com/500/e?cas5=Other&cas11=Web&cas14=Hello StackOverflow&cas15=Some long text here`

To be safe you should urlencode the parameters though.